# How to pass appsetting and databind in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i want to pass a appsetting value and sqldatasource value into gridview to generate a URL for user to click.

e.g.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="VirtualIP" value="http://192.168.1.1/wcm" /> 
  </appSettings>
```

---

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="select MeetingID, MeetName as MeetingName, MeetDate, Year(MeetDate) as MeetYear, Month(MeetDate) as MeetMth, MeetTime, convert(varchar, MeetDate, 111) + ' ' + convert(varchar, MeetTime, 108) AS ShowTime from Meeting where Status ='Recorded' order by MeetDate desc, Meettime desc ">

<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="MeetingID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString=""  DataTextField="MeetingID" DataTextFormatString="<img src='images/Audio_1.png'  border='0' />" />
```

moreover, i want to add MeetYear and MeetMth as folder in URL

how to assign value in DataNavigateUrlFormatString ?

```
<%appSettings: VirtualIP%> / MeetYear / MeetMth / {0}.wma
```

to become

http://192.168.1.1/wcm/2011/12/M11234.wma

regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%# appSettings: VirtualIP%> / MeetYear / MeetMth / {0}.wma`
`#` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$` [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx).

```
<%$ appSettings: VirtualIP %>
```